# Why are runtime.js, styles.js created on ng serve command

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular6, angular-cli

Greetings fellow programmers

I am new to angular and I wanted to know why are these two files created when I run *ng serve* command.

[these are the files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZG9PT.png)

I know why other 3 files are created (main.js, polyfills.js, vendor.js) but I don't know about the 2 files I mentioned (runtime.js, styles.js)

I tried googling it too but no information came on these two files.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: They're self explanatory. As they're internal to Angular, I don't think you need to focus on that while learning Angular. Consider that one contains runtime configuration for your app, and the other its styles.

Answer (score 1):

I am not good in explanation but let me give my understanding on these things. Its basically **webpack** (AOT compailer) configuration which continuously watch your changes on code, if change detect its compile all files and convert in minimized version.

1. **runtime.js** : Contains all files (Component, module, services, pipes, etc.) convert into js and transform into minimized version.
2. **styles.js** : same for css files.

i hope you get idea from this.

Comment: then what is main.js?