# What is runtime.26209474bfa8dc87a77c.js?

Tags: angular

I have inherited what I assume to be some sort of "bundled" Angular application. The folder contents are posted below. Can anyone point me to what sort of tool would likely have been used to create these files?

[image]

Comment: Maybe checking `3rdpartylicenses.txt` could be worth a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are the compiled files from an angular application
Created after someone ran the command ng build
Using the Angular CLI
https://cli.angular.io/

Comment: It might be worth noting that those files can be used to deploy the app in its current state, but without the original source files OP won't be able to make any changes to the app

Comment: @elf337: thanks for that confirmation - I thought that would be the case. As you can tell, I've got a lot to learn...

Answer (score 0):

> runtime.js: Contains all files (Component, module, services, pipes, etc.) convert into js and transform into minimized version.

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53668325/3151567)